# Check whether branch changes were manually merged

Tags: git

I have a non-merged branch but I suspect its changes have already been integrated manually without using git (bad, I know).

Diffing it with master will show tons of changes.

How can I check whether branch changes are present in master?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "without using git", I'm going to assume you mean someone possibly made the same (or similar) changes again in a new commit on the target branch, but did not use `cherry-pick` or `merge`.

In this case you could try rebasing your branch onto the target branch. Changes that were done similarly or identically in both branches will either cause a conflict (and your answer will be obvious) or the changes will vanish. After you're done, look at the newly rewritten commits on your branch to see what's left, if anything.

**Side note:** if your organizational workflow allows for it (and most do), I would highly recommend rebasing your (non-collaborative) feature branch onto the target regularly to keep it up to date, and again just before completing a PR into the target branch. In this way you *automatically* learn if someone else made the same change as you did and completed their PR ahead of you, and this has multiple other benefits as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try merging your branch with master nevertheless. One of the two things will happen -

**CASE 1**: The changes were not integrated into the master branch earlier.

In this scenario, you'll be able to merge your branch in master without any issues and most likely with very few conflicts in your code.

**CASE 2**: The changes were integrated into the master branch manually.

In this scenario, when you'll merge your branch with master, you are more likely to get conflicts as `git` will detect that similar changes are there in your files. By looking at the conflicts, you'll immediately get to know that the changes were merged manually.

You can then abort the merge if you don't want to proceed further with `git merge --abort`.